# How to return a subset of object properties from a Spring Boot restful GET call?

Tags: java, json, rest

Newbie question...

I'm building my first Spring Boot restful service and want to support a GET call that returns a collection of entities. like:

```
/api/customers/
```

However, for certain consumers -like a list page in a web UI - they would only need a subset of the customer entity properties.

I'm thinking that I could add request parameters to my GET call to set the consumers specific field requirements, like

```
/api/customers/?fields=id,name,address
```

But what's the best way of implementing this inside the Java restful controller?

Currently in my rest controller the 'GET' is request mapped to a Java method, like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public Customer[] getList() {
  Customer[] anArray = new Customer[];
  ....
  return anArray;
}
```

Is it possible to somehow intervene with the default Java to Json response body translation so that only the required properties are included?

TIA

Comment: Are the number of subsets previously known, or the consumers can ask for any combination of fields? What about nested fields? You may wanna look at the [Facebook graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/) which does what you're looking for. `GET graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,picture`

Comment: I see there being two main fields subset scenarios:  simple list, where only customer id and name are required; and table list, where additional properties might be required like: address, contact number, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `fields` parameter is a good idea, best practice according to http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#limiting-fields

How to leave fields out?

1) Set them to `null`, possibly in a dedicated output class annotated with `@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`

Or

2) Use [SimpleBeanPropertyFilter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.html) See a good step by step tutorial [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization) *5. Ignore Fields Using Filters*